# Django .extra() Not Workin As I Expect

Tags: django, postgresql

I'm using  Python 3.2.3, Django 1.5, and PostgreSQL.

I must not be understanding something about using `.extra()`, but I'm absolutely clueless what I'm missing. This seems like it should work, from what I've read.

Let's say I've got a model that includes these fields:

```
vscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,
                                          verbose_name="Visitors Score")
hscore = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(blank=True,null=True,
                                          verbose_name="Home Score")
```

And I'm using this piece of code to get some data from it:

```
vstats = Game.objects.filter(start_et__range=[start,end],
                                     ).values(
                                     'vteam').annotate(
                                      vgames=Count('vteam'),
                                      vscore=Sum('vscore'),
                                      hscore=Sum('hscore'),
                                      vscoreAVG=Avg('vscore'),
                                      hscoreAVG=Avg('hscore')).extra(
                    select={'vwins': "sum(vscore>hscore)"})
```

It works fine, except for the `extra()`, which I'm using to try to get the number of rows where the vscore is greater than the hscore. I don't even get a `vwins` key in the resulting dictionary tho, so I'm guessing that I'm somehow not using this right. That's where I'm totally puzzled, 'cause I copy-n-pasted this straight from [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#extra) and altered the SQL bit to fit my needs. Why doesn't the `vstats` dictionary include a `vwins` key?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with the [`values()` method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values).

Here's the relevant quote from the Django docs:

> If you use a values() clause after an extra() call, any fields defined by a select argument in the extra() must be explicitly included in the values() call. Any extra() call made after a values() call will have its extra selected fields ignored.

So what you probably want is:

```
vstats = Game.objects.filter(start_et__range=[start,end],
                                 ).annotate(
                                  vgames=Count('vteam'),
                                  vscore=Sum('vscore'),
                                  hscore=Sum('hscore'),
                                  vscoreAVG=Avg('vscore'),
                                  hscoreAVG=Avg('hscore')).extra(
                select={'vwins': "sum(vscore>hscore)"}).values(
                                 'vteam', 'vwins', 'vgames', 'vscore', 'hscore',
                                 'vscoreAVG', 'hscoreAVG')
```

This query will include the code you want in the `SELECT` clause, but it will fail, because it will produce incorrect `SQL` code.

Comment: Thanks! I think that's working 'cause/but now Django's saying there's a DB error -- "function sum(boolean) does not exist", which just can't be true 'cause the PostgreSQL 9.0 docs say there is http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/functions-aggregate.html